# I want to verify if placeholders of my settings (manifest.jps) are set or not to use them in my bash (bash called in manifest)

Tags: bash, manifest, jelastic

I develop a plugin for deploy app Angular/React/Vue in simple click.
So, i trie to verify if the value of the placeholder is set or not to use it or not in my bash script call.
Actually i try to redirect my differents "if" in actions.
The differents scenarios of my plugins are:

- client gives is public git ( so i just use the url )
- client gives is public git with a specific folder of build app result
  ( in angular/vue its often /dist and in react it can be /build)

  by default if you dont specify the folder, the default value in my bash    is /dist (because its the classic folder)
- client gives private git with token
- client gives private git with token and a specific folder of build

So in this topic i show you my manifest.jps and the bash script to understand my problem.

I hope you can help me :) ( and sorry for my english i trie to amelior it)

```
settings:
  fields:
  - name: gitRepo
    caption: Git Repo Url*
    type: string
    required: true
    default: ''
    regex: "^https?:\\/\\/.+$"
    regexText: Incorrect URL. HTTPS link to Git repository is required.
  - name: gitToken
    caption: Token
    type: string
    required: false
    default: ''
  - name: buildPath
    caption: your path for build
    type: string
    required: false
    default: ''

onInstall:

- if ( ${settings.gitToken} && ${settings.buildPath} && ${settings.gitRepo} ): totalScript


- if ( ${settings.gitRepo} && ${settings.gitToken} ): scriptToken


- if ( ${settings.gitRepo} && ${settings.buildPath} ): scriptPath

- if ( ${settings.gitRepo} ): scriptRepo

actions:
  totalScript:
    cmd [cp]: 
            - curl -fsS https://raw.githubusercontent.com/user/scripts-sources/master/test-settings.sh | /bin/bash -s ${settings.gitRepo} -t ${settings.gitToken} -p ${settings.buildPath}

    scriptToken:
      cmd [cp]: 
              - curl -fsS https://raw.githubusercontent.com/user/scripts-sources/master/test-settings.sh | /bin/bash -s ${settings.gitRepo} -t ${settings.gitToken}


    scriptPath:
       cmd [cp]: 
            - curl -fsS https://raw.githubusercontent.com/user/scripts-sources/master/test-settings.sh | /bin/bash -s ${settings.gitRepo} -p ${settings.buildPath}

    scriptRepo:
       cmd [cp]: 
            - curl -fsS https://raw.githubusercontent.com/user/scripts-sources/master/test-settings.sh | /bin/bash -s ${settings.gitRepo}
```

test-settings.sh (this script works, i show it because its the link with my manifest)

```
#!/bin/bash
link=$1 


# Options
#
while getopts "htp" OPTION
do
        case $OPTION in
                h)
                        usage
                        ;;
                t)      token=$OPTARG



                        ;;
                p)      pathBuild_form=$OPTARG

                        ;;
        esac
done




if [[ -z "$token"  ]]
  then
    if [[ $link == *".git"* ]];
    then
      repo="https://"$(echo $link |  cut -d'/' -f4 )@$(echo $link | cut -d'/' -f3)/$(echo $link |  cut -d'/' -f4)/$(echo $link |  cut -d'/' -f5)
    else
      repo="https://"$(echo $link |  cut -d'/' -f4 )@$(echo $link | cut -d'/' -f3)/$(echo $link |  cut -d'/' -f4)/$(echo $link |  cut -d'/' -f5).git
    fi
  else
    if [[ $link == *".git"* ]];
    then
      repo="https://"$(echo $link |  cut -d'/' -f4 ):$token@$(echo $link | cut -d'/' -f3)/$(echo $link |  cut -d'/' -f4)/$(echo $link |  cut -d'/' -f5)
    else
      repo="https://"$(echo $link |  cut -d'/' -f4 ):$token@$(echo $link | cut -d'/' -f3)/$(echo $link |  cut -d'/' -f4)/$(echo $link |  cut -d'/' -f5).git
    fi
fi
git clone $repo

pathBuild=$(echo $link |  cut -d'/' -f5 | cut -f1 -d".")

npm install --prefix ./$pathBuild
npm run build --prefix ./$pathBuild




if [[ ! -z "$pathBuild_form"  ]]
 then
   mv $pathBuild/$pathBuild_form/* /home/jacqueax/MyApp
 else
   var=$(ls $pathBuild/dist)
   if [[ $var == *"index"* ]]; then
     mv $pathBuild/dist/* /home/jacqueax/MyApp
   else
     mv dist/$var/* /home/jacqueax/MyApp
   fi
fi
rm -rf $pathBuild
```

So for the moment i see this in log when the client just put the public git :

WARNING: if (  &&  && https://github.com/user/js-app-forBuild ): invalid condition. Response: {"result":1704,"line":3,"response":null,"source":"hx-core","error":"org.mozilla.javascript.EvaluatorException: syntax error"}

---> this line correspond of my first "if"; others log are similary

I just want to verify if the placeholder is set or not.Actually the values of placeholder is used and its not that i want ( because if the token for example is not put in settings the "if" where there are token var will be empty and "if" failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Placeholders may be replaced with a default value or with an empty string.
All listed IF functions might look like:

```
if ( '${settings.gitToken:}' && '${settings.buildPath:}' && '${settings.gitRepo:}' ): totalScript
```

or

```
if ( settings.gitToken && settings.buildPath && settings.gitRepo ): totalScript
```

Check our documentation [Default Values of Placeholders](https://docs.cloudscripting.com/creating-manifest/placeholders/#default-values-of-placeholders)